# How to flip entire awt.Canvas vertically

Tags: java, canvas, awt, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am sitting with my son, trying to implement a school homework. The task is to write a program that draws X and Y axis and functions, e.g. Sinus or x² into a awt.Canvas. The issue we are struggeling with is that the root, Point(0,0) of the Canvas is designed to be in the upper left corner. The cartesian coordinate system that we have to have, has the origin in the lower left corner. So we tried to apply a AffineTransform and translate in the paint method of the Canvas, which in essence works but has two issues:

1st, for whatever reason the related translation doesn't really moves the origin to the bottom but about 100 pixels to high (see image).
When we put in the below code an additional offset of about 100 pixels with `tx.translate(0, -(getHeight()+100));` it looks about right.Same issue seems to be true on the right side. There is also unintended free space. We colored the background of the containing Frame in black and the Canvas in grey to exclude an artefact between these two containers. But doesn't seem to be the case.

2nd, and that concerns us more, is the side effect that all text, when e.g. adding values to the axes will also be fliped, as you see at our debug info in the plotAxes method.

Here is what we have done so far..

```
public class PlotterView extends Canvas {

protected int MINWIDTH = 500;
protected int MINHEIGHT = 400;

Point[][] lines;

public PlotterView() {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(MINWIDTH, MINHEIGHT);
    setPreferredSize(dim);
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}

protected void plotAxes(Graphics2D g) {
    
    Color defaultColor = g.getColor();  // save to restore defaults in the end
    int originX = 5;   // x origin of both axes - shift right
    int originY = 5;   // y origin of both axis - shift up
    
    // Debug info to compare
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("X: " + originX + "; Y: " + originY, originX, originY);

    // X-Axis
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(originX, originY, MINWIDTH-20, originY);
    g.drawLine(MINWIDTH-20, originY, MINWIDTH-30, originY-5);
    g.drawLine(MINWIDTH-20, originY, MINWIDTH-30, originY+5);

    // Y-Axis
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine(originX, originY,  originX, MINHEIGHT-20);
    g.drawLine(originX, MINHEIGHT-20, originX-5, MINHEIGHT-30);
    g.drawLine(originX, MINHEIGHT-20, originX+5, MINHEIGHT-30);
    
    // Restore defaults
    g.setColor(defaultColor);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1);
    tx.translate(0, -getHeight());
    g2.setTransform(tx);

    plotAxes(g2);
}
}
```

One alternative would be to implement a method that "adjusts" every x-value from upper left to lower left, but that feels like a kind of botch job.

How to solve this right? Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be on Java? ... I get a feeling you will get an easier job using an HTML canvas and there are plenty of libraries to make your job easier

Comment: Nope. The Teacher asked for java.awt.Canvas or java.awt.Panel

Comment: In that case then you need to troubleshoot what is going... this question feels like you have multiple issues try to break them down and ask one question per issue, first thing that sticks out like a sore thumb is the upside down `drawString` could that be caused by the negative value in your `AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1)` ?

Comment: ... and to make it easier for anyone attempting to troubleshoot your problem maybe add a working sample to an online compiler like: https://onecompiler.com/java

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. I figured out that issue number 1 is born by using the AffineTransform. If I apply the scale and translate on the g2 directly the issue disappears.

Issue number 2 is a conflict of interest. We couldn't manage to find and apply the "three magic lines of code" (or whatever number would be required) to from thereon programm in a cartesian coordinate system. Instead we are converting all y-values into this top-level-origin coordinate system. Makes the code hard to read, but with the help debugging we managed.